# Find duplicates ok, but why delete doesn't work?

Tags: postgresql

I try to clean table from an open-source building database.

First step is to find duplicates, for that I use

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nbr_doublon, type_local, date_mutation, valeur_fonciere, adresse_code_voie, adresse_nom_voie, adresse_suffixe, adresse_numero, type_local, surface_reelle_bati
FROM     dvf_2018
WHERE type_local='Dépendance'
GROUP BY type_local, date_mutation, valeur_fonciere, adresse_code_voie, adresse_nom_voie, adresse_suffixe, adresse_numero, type_local, surface_reelle_bati
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

Ok, duplicates are identified, but what is the best way to conserve only one for any entry ?

Trying

```
DELETE 
FROM dvf_2018 t1 
USING dvf_2018 t2
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
AND t1.type_local='Dépendance'
AND t2.type_local='Dépendance'
AND t1.date_mutation = t2.date_mutation
AND t1.valeur_fonciere = t2.valeur_fonciere
AND t1.adresse_code_voie = t2.adresse_code_voie
AND t1.adresse_nom_voie = t2.adresse_nom_voie
AND t1.adresse_suffixe = t2.adresse_suffixe
AND t1.adresse_numero = t2.adresse_numero
AND t1.type_local = t2.type_local
AND t1.surface_reelle_bati = t2.surface_reelle_bati
```

But deleting 0 row, why ? What is the best way to do ? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the `id` is equal or NULL.

Comment: All of the `surface_reelle_bati` shown in your screenshot are `NULL`. `t1.surface_reelle_bati = t2.surface_reelle_bati` won't evaluate to `true` for those.

Comment: use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` in stead of `=`